# is it safe to share the indexes folder between computers?

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup

my understsanding is the `indexes` folder is created if you have `tindex` set to 1 and want to keep an index of all transactions. all of the material i've seen (bitcoin core documentation, on this site, etc) either:

- says it's safe to copy only `blocks` + `chainstate` between computers
- lists files + folders which are expressly *unsafe* to copy (ex. `wallet.dat`).

my understanding + intuition of the `indexes` folder (from docs + inspecting the files myself) is that it has no pii and should be safe to copy but i just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `indexes` is safe to copy. It only contains transaction data and is completely unrelated to the wallet. In fact, `indexes` used to be part of `blocks` so with older versions, if you had `txindex=1`, then copying `blocks` meant you also copied `indexes`. Only recently was this separated into its own folder in the datadir.